# Remove adres after slash “/”

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

How I can remove adress after slash “/” ?
Change it:

```
google.pl/urlTodel/how-remove-adress
```

to this:

```
google.pl/how-remove-adress
```

and I want to take urlTodel as par1 in htaccess

Now I get par1 by this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)$ /index.php?par1=$1
```

Example

```
 google.pl/urlTodel/how-remove-adress
 $_GET['par1'] is urlTodel
```

Comment: If you really want `urlTodel` in your PHP code then why do you want to delete it from URL?

Comment: Look I have page localhost/news then I go into single news then page look like this localhost/news/news-name and I want have localhost/news-name

Comment: There is no reason to hide or remove `/new/` from URL if you want it in your PHP code. It doesn't even help SEO